# Ignore multiple entries of word boundary inside capturing group of + Quantifier

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have this regex `/{([\d,-]+)}/` which is used to highlight lines in markdown and allows input in this format - `{2,3-6,8}`. Now, I wanted to include `showLineNumbers` prop in it too such as `{2,3-6,8,showLineNumbers}`  and couldn't figure regex for this. I have tried this regex `/{([\d\bshowLineNumbers\b,-]+)}/`  but this still results in matched in following examples:

- `{1,2,3,ssssss}`
- `{1,2,3,show}`

But the expected value, should only have `showLineNumbers` prop one time, inside the curly brackets regardless of position. For eg: `{showLineNumbers,3,5,6}`, `{3,5, showLineNumbers,6}`, etcetera. should match the regex format. Where did I make a mistake in this format - `/{([\d\bshowLineNumbers\b,-]+)}/`  ?

Comment: You have a character class where you need an alternation `/{([\d, -]|\bshowLineNumbers\b)+}/`

Comment: Thanks @Nick , I understand the problem now.